# ListView items overwriting the existing items

Tags: android, listview, overwrite

This is how I'm trying to add items to listView. But unfortunately its deleting the old items and adding new item instead of appending to the old items.

```
     // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView
            .findViewById(R.id.list_text);
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
    final List<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list, MyList);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    String NewListname = editText.getText().toString();
                    MyList.add(NewListname);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Can anyone say me how do I add them ?

Comment: Did you check MyList's data in OK's onclick in debug mode? Does it contain old data as well?

Comment: @MysticMagic-No the old data was not there.

Comment: dont use `new ArrayList<String>();` if its already defined.. just add items to it and call  `adp.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is:

Your ArrayList data is being overwritten due to its initialization inside:

```
final List<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Make it global variable. And just add data to it inside

```
MyList.add(NewListname);
```

Or just add item to adapter.

```
adp.add(NewListname);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` has the [add(T obj)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)) method. Just call

```
adp.add(NewListname);
```

Answer (score 0):

**use the following code :**

```
 MyList.add(NewListname);
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
        R.layout.list, MyList);
 adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**instead of :**

```
  MyList.add(NewListname);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, NewListname,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```